# Python script sends too much requests at once to API (python-binance)

Tags: python, binance, binance-api-client

The script I use seems to send request too quickly to the API. If requests are queued more than 100 times the API send this error and stops:

```
{'e': 'error', 'm': 'Queue overflow. Message not filled'}
```

The script part that sends and receives is the following:

```
while True:
    await socket.__aenter__()
    msg = await socket.recv()
    frame = createframe(msg)
    frame.to_sql(symbol, engine, if_exists="append", index=False)
    print(frame)
```

As it can be seen in the time in printed frames that the request are send very quickly.

```
    Symbol                    Time     Price
0  BTCUSDT 2021-09-23 21:30:15.009  44663.17
    Symbol                    Time     Price
0  BTCUSDT 2021-09-23 21:30:15.061  44663.17
    Symbol                    Time     Price
0  BTCUSDT 2021-09-23 21:30:15.061  44663.17
    Symbol                    Time     Price
0  BTCUSDT 2021-09-23 21:30:15.133  44663.17
    Symbol                    Time     Price
0  BTCUSDT 2021-09-23 21:30:15.190  44663.17
    Symbol                    Time     Price
0  BTCUSDT 2021-09-23 21:30:15.261  44663.17
    Symbol                    Time     Price
0  BTCUSDT 2021-09-23 21:30:15.261  44663.17
```

In the ideal case there should be 1 request every second. However, the script seems to barrage the API with requests. I tried the time.sleep() function but it seems that it does not work to stabilize the request speed.

Comment: Could you provide code sample of how you introduced time.sleep() ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to sleep?

```py
import asyncio, time
...
last_request_time = 0.0
while True:
    # Calculate delay from now to the moment of previous request + 1 sec
    # btw, it's Ok to sleep negative delays as well, so we don't need an `if`
    delay = last_request_time + 1.0 - time.monotonic()
    await asyncio.sleep(delay)  # sleep
    last_request_time = time.monotonic()  # write timestamp at the moment of the new request
    await socket.__aenter__()  # That's bad, use `async with` instead 
    msg = await socket.recv()
    
    frame = createframe(msg)
    frame.to_sql(symbol, engine, if_exists="append", index=False)
    print(frame)  # <- That's bad, `print()` is blocking
```

Comment: No, sorry this did not work. I think now it is due to the python or jupyter version. Because it should have worked but still the script sends too much requests at once.